# Adding 2 Integers using AWT

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to create a Java AWT program with these codes:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Exer1 extends JFrame {

    public Exer1(){

        super ("Addition");
        JLabel add1 = new JLabel("Enter 1st Integer: ");
        JTextField jtf1 = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel add2 = new JLabel("Enter 2nd Integer: ");
        JTextField jtf2 = new JTextField(10);
        JButton calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
        FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(flo);
        add(add1);
        add(jtf1);
        add(add2);
        add(jtf2);
        add(calculate);
        setSize(200,200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] a){
        Exer1 ex1 = new Exer1();
    }

}
```

My problem is HOW to add these 2 integers using JTextField. Can someone help me? Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) on your `JButton`.

Then you need to get `int`'s from `JTextField`'s and sum them like next:

```
calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                int i1 = Integer.valueOf(jtf1.getText());
                int i2 = Integer.valueOf(jtf2.getText());
                System.out.println("sum=" + (i1 + i2));
            } catch (Exception e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should create an event listener for click events on your button: [Lesson: Writing Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/). In that handler, you would take contents of your two text fields, convert them to integers:

```
Integer i1 = Integer.valueOf(jtf1.getText());
```

Then you can add those two integers and display them in another control or do anything else with them.

Answer (score 1):

Start with [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and 
[How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

This will provide you with the information you need to be able to tell when the user presses the button.

`JTextField#getText` then return's `String`. The problem then becomes a problem of converting a `String` to a `int`, which if you take the time, there are thousands of examples demonstrating how to achieve that

Once you've played around with oddities of converting `String` to a `int`, you could take a look at [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) and [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) which perform there own validation on the values been entered